# Which function in the Schwarz class of functions is "closest" to triangle wave in $L^2$ sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, approximation, computational-mathematics, smooth-functions

Would it be possible to calculate which function in the Schwarz class of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support is closest to triangle wave?

Let us measure closeness as $$<f-g,f-g>_{L_2}^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x)-g(x))^2dx$$

I don't expect my knowledge in functional analysis to be strong and polished enough to answer this, but maybe one of you guys know how to?

---

**EDIT** of course we need to edit triangle wave to have compact support. Say it has compact support on $$x \in [-1-2N,1+2N], N\in \mathbb Z_+$$
In other words, $2N+1$ whole periods and it goes down to $0$ just at both ends of support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class of Schwartz class is not closed with respect to the $L^2$ norm, so there isn't necessarily a closest element. Indeed, in this case there isn't, as you can find arbitrarily close functions (take for instance convolutions with an [approximate identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function)), but the triangle wave itself is not in the Schwartz.

Comment: Ah ok. I suspected something like it. Bit sad, but it helps me formulate better questions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is no "closest" Schwarz function to a given $L^2$ function. Since the Schwarz class is dense in $L^2$, we can find Schwarz functions arbitrarily close to any $L^2$ function. Indeed, let $f \in L^2(\mathbb R^n) \setminus \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ and let $f_0 \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ be any Schwarz function. Then we can always find $f_* \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ with, for example, $$\|f - f_*\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} <  \frac 1 2 \| f - f_{0} \|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}.$$ Thus we can iteratively construct a sequence such that each member is "closer" to $f$ than the previous.